# specify source files when using snakemake remote prefix

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

From the docs:

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html

> Currently, this mode requires that the Snakemake workflow is stored in a git repository. Snakemake uses git to query necessary source files (the Snakefile, scripts, config, …) for workflow execution and encodes them into the kubernetes job.

However, what is not clear to me is how to specify source files as stated. `srcdir` returns the absolute path with the specified prefix prepended.

Could someone please point me to the relevant area of the docs please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with kubernetics and Snakemake, but I am assuming using the 'default' structure should work. You can easily generate this structure with the snakemake cookiecutter repo:
https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/cookiecutter-snakemake-workflow

Just make sure cookiecutter is installed and you can run this on the command-line:

```
cookiecutter https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/cookiecutter-snakemake-workflow
```

Or you can always just take a look at where files are stored in that repo and copy the structure.